# Bloated Session Struct:

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I understand the basic differences between structs and class types. But, in an ASP.NET WebForms application...what is the ideal container type to hold a relatively large data structure in Session in an ASP.NET WebForms application? Should it be a struct or class? For example...

```
Public Structure SessionData     

 Public ShipVias As List(Of XXXXX999.sycdefil_sql_VW)
 Public ShipTos As List(Of XXXXX999.ABC_Web_ShipTo_VW)
 Public Dests As List(Of XXXXX999.ABC_Web_CofA_VW)
 Public Owners As List(Of XXXXX999.ABC_Web_CofA_VW)

 Public Carts As List(Of XXXXX999.ABC_Web_Cart_VW)
 Public Carriers As List(Of XXXXX999.ABC_Carrier_Accounts_VW)

 Public Countries As List(Of XXXXX999.usp_get_CountryListResult)
 Public States As List(Of XXXXX999.usp_get_StatesListResult)

 Public POItems As List(Of XXXXX999.usp_get_cart_infoResult)

 Public SearchResults As List(Of SearchResult)
 Public Addresses As List(Of AddressResult)

 Public CartItems As List(Of itemsdetail)

 Public POs As List(Of POResult)

 Public SomeCollection As Collection
 Public CmpCode As String
 Public CmpStatus As String
 Public CmpSIPCust As String
 Public CurrentSession As String
 Public AllowAccess As Boolean

 Public QuickAddItems As List(Of QuickAddItem)

End Structure
```

As you can probably tell, XXXXX999 contains a  LINQTOSQL DataContext dbml containing sprocs, functions, views and tables.

Edit point: I just realized I can make a struct(C#) to be nullable...In vb.net Nullable(Of SessionData)...also question mark does the trick like so...
Dim sd As SessionData?
Should I keep this as a Structure or convert it to a Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a class.  Based on this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) a struct should only be used if:

> **Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.**
>
> **Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:**
>
> 1. It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> 2. It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> 3. It is immutable.
> 4. It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Answer (score 1):

if you are dealing with distinct values I would use a dictionary that hold dictionaries for every type of list